# Implement vertical scroll-bar in DropDown List

Tags: javascript, css, xslt

I have 3 dropdowns in my page. When i select data from 1-st dropdown, it populates 2nd  dropdown. If second dropdown data has at least two times more characters than 1st dropdown, it would expand the page, which looks very poor. I want to introduce vertical scroll-bar in dropdown list, so that the page size doesn't expand.

Comment: Are You using some kind of plugin for your dropdown? jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

`$('select').attr('size', 5);` for example sets the max visible items ... if they are more ...a scrollbar will appear ...